# How to Create a React Native Audio Guide App (Streaming)

Tags: audio, react-native, streaming

I'm noobie in programming, I'm trying to create an audio guide app usign react native and Expo. My problem: how can I stream the audio guide to the app?

Comment: I'm looking for the same !..Are you using images also ??Got any solution from any other sources ??